# Geospatial API for Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, geospatial

I was found this: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/geospatial, but I can't find anything about using this in Flutter. It's a bit weird Google didn't mention it with Flutter.
Has someone find some info if this will be available for Flutter?

Comment: hello, did you find out how it works with flutter?

Comment: Nothing, I didn't see much about for Android either.

Comment: I found this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/ar_location_view, I hope it helps you.

Comment: This is awesome package but it doesn't use geospatial api.